# I want to combine 1D and 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
|   Column_A   |           Column_B                   |             Column_C                 | 
| 0.91512748   | [1.22773944 1.34972084  ...   0. ]   | [1.22773944 1.34972084  ...   0. ]   |
| 1.09939718   | [0.36013158 1.0634674   ...   0. ]   | [1.22773944 1.34972084  ...   0. ]   |
| 1.10390337   | 0.70320446 0.82676872   ...   0. ]   | [1.22773944 1.34972084  ...   0. ]   |
|      ...     |             ...                      |                  ...                 |
|      ...     |             ...                      |                  ...                 |
|      ...     |             ...                      |                  ...                 |
|      ...     |             ...                      |                  ...                 |
```

I want my numpy data stored in this manner. In reality Column_A, Column_B and Column_C are stored in different variable.
Column_A has dimension (8741).
Column_B has dimension (8741,60).
Column_C has dimension (8741,60).

I have looked for different solutions but they are suggesting to change the dimension of my data.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do in the end?

Comment: `result = np.hstack((ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC))` maybe?

Comment: You might also consider using pandas DataFrames.

Comment: @AKX I am trying to combine my data and use them for training NN.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried that but it only works when the dimension of arrays is same.

Comment: @Malcolm Yes. I have tried as mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: If `A` is (n,1) you could concatenate them on axis 1 and get a (n, 1+60+60) array with a numeric dtype.  This would be cleanest for calculations, but you loose the distinction between the 3 original arrays. You could make a (3,) object dtype array, but such an array is little better (and maybe worse) than a list, `[A,B,C[`.  A dataframe with 8000 rows and 3 columns is possible, but do you really want 3*8000 cells with 1 to 60 element arrays in each?

Comment: The "correct" data structure to use depends on how you are going to use the data.  Using simple lists there is the choice of having [Column_A_array, Column_B_array, Column_C_array] vs. [[Column_A[0], Column_B[0], Column_C[0]],...].  Which is better depends upon what you need to use at the same time.  The advantage of Pandas is that it lets you access your data efficiently either way.  However, if you really need your columns to be numpy arrays for the numerical operations you are going to perform on them, then [ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC] (or numpy.hstack ala @MarkSetchell) might be best.